# Unable to close AlertDialog after onResume()

Tags: android, android-dialog

I checking when the activity starts up whether Location Services are turned on or not, if not I am opening a dialog that starts the "Enable Location Activity" intent. Once I am returning from it I am checking if the location has really been enabled or not, if so I am dismissing the alert dialog.

In theory this should work, but when my activity resumes and call `dialog.dismiss()` absolutely nothing happens.

My code is as follows-:

```
public class LocationUtils {

private static AlertDialog dialog_ = null;

public static void checkAndEnableLocationServices(final Activity context) {
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean gps_enabled = false;
    boolean network_enabled = false;

    try {
        gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        network_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("gps_enabled = " + gps_enabled);
    System.out.println("network_enabled = " + network_enabled);

    if (!gps_enabled && !network_enabled) {
        // notify user
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        builder.setMessage("Location services are disabled");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Enable Location Services", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                context.startActivity(myIntent);
                //get gps
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                context.finish();
            }
        });
        //For future reference.
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

        dialog_ = dialog;

        dialog.show();
    } else {
        if(dialog_!=null) {
            dialog_.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

}

In my main activity I have a onResume callback that does the following-:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    System.out.println("Activity resume()");
    LocationUtils.checkAndEnableLocationServices(this);
}
```

What am I missing ? Why is this is dialog not closing ? The code is not throwing any errors. This a WTF moment for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are calling alertDialog.show method for the local alert dialog.
Replace code,

```
   AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog_ = dialog;
```

with

```
 dialog_ =  builder.create();
 dialog_.show
```

and onResume()

```
    if(dialog_!=null) {
        dialog_.dismiss();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo can dismiss dialog when positive button clicked and show it in OnResume if Location Service not enambled